# undefined reference to slCreateEngine

Tags: visual-studio, android-ndk, opensl

I want to play sound through opensl. Connected library Linker-> Input-> Library Dependencies - OpenSLES. The linker produces an error - undefined reference to slCreateEngine.

Comment: Did you add OpenSLES to target_link_libraries in CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: What relation has CMakeLists.txt to Visual Studio?

Comment: You should also have a path to the lib specified. What do you have in Additional Library Directories?

Answer (score 4):

check your target_link_libraries method inside **CmakeLists.txt** if it has all the necessary libraries included..

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        android
        log
        OpenSLES)
```

Comment: in my case OpenSLES was missing.